# How to remove Vertical Lines in image opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I wanted to remove both horizontal and vertical lines the following code works well to remove horizontal lines but in this

[image: Original Image]

Here is the output image where the horizontal line is removed

[image: Horizontal line Removed]

Here is the code attached please can you tell me how can I remove the vertical lines

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
def remove_lines(image_path,outdir):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    result = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Remove horizontal lines
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
    remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    
    cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)


    # Remove vertical lines
    vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
    remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
    #remove_vertical =cv2.dilate(remove_vertical , vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)

    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(image_path)), result)
    plt.imshow(result)
for jpgfile in glob.glob(r'C:\custom\TableDetectionWork\images/*'):
    print(jpgfile)
    remove_lines(jpgfile,r'C:\custom\TableDetectionWork\output/')
```

Comment: One approach is to rotate the image 90 deg, then apply your same code, then rotate back 90 deg.  Another approach is to change your horizontal kernel to a vertical kernel in your morphology.

Comment: Horizontal kernel to vertical kernel? Can't understand

Comment: ah right, my bad. well, your vertical lines are very short, so you should change the kernel size.

Comment: Which kernel size is suitable for that kind of line? i try many Kernal but does not work. Can you share some process?

Answer (score 2):

To remove both lines:

```py
msk = im.copy()
msk = cv2.medianBlur(msk, 11)
msk = cv2.erode(msk, np.ones((5, 5)))
msk = cv2.threshold(msk, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
msk = cv2.GaussianBlur(msk, (5, 0), 11)
msk = cv2.threshold(msk, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
msk = cv2.erode(msk, np.ones((31, 31)))
im[np.where(msk != 0)] = 255
```